# Getting php variable from text field

Tags: php, variables, split, textfield

I can't get name from text field as php variable to split into firstname and lastname.

Here is my code:

```
<form action="split.php" metod="POST">
<input type="text" id="pcategory" name="fullname" value="Jason Bill">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['fullname'])){
$name = $_POST['fullname'];
} 
echo $name;
$parts = explode(" ", $name);
$lastname = array_pop($parts);
$firstname = implode(" ", $parts);
echo "Lastname: $lastname\n";
echo "Firstname: $firstname\n";
?>
</form>
```

I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\ordinacija\split.php on line 9 Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\ordinacija\split.php on line 11

Comment: You need to add the code or show us something. You have an `input` field a user is entering the name into and you want to split the first name and last?

Comment: If you want value from textfield without reloading you should be using Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You're not defining `$_POST['fullname']` on the first load of this page, so that's why you're getting a notice.

Add all the logic in the `if ( isset($_POST['fullname']) )` block:

```
<!-- Ensure you're submitting the page to itself. This code here should be in 'split.php' -->
<form action="split.php" metod="POST">
<input type="text" id="pcategory" name="fullname" value="Jason Bill">
<?php
if( isset($_POST['fullname']) ) {
  $name      = $_POST['fullname'];
  $parts     = explode(" ", $name);
  $lastname  = array_pop($parts);
  $firstname = implode(" ", $parts);

  echo "$name\n";
  echo "Lastname: $lastname\n";
  echo "Firstname: $firstname\n";
} else {
  echo 'No name has been submitted yet';
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Get full name" />
</form>
```